# asp.net DropDown does not change selected item clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

On my ASP.Net page i used js plugin from [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/). i got nice custom form elements suiting the look and feel of my site. Later i Noticed that when i applied the `Styled` css class on my asp.net dropdown list controls and set it's `AutoPostback` property to `false`, i can not see the selected value changing on clientside. However when i click a button on my page the SelectedValue posted to server is changing but UI not updating without post to server.

i see js file provided by **ryan** and observed if i remove `opacity` or `filter`(in ie) the dropdown starts working fine, but unfortunately that disturbs the look and feel of `DropDownList`. the `opacity` is set dynamically using cutom-form .js

Particularly this line of code sets the `opacity` of elements

```
document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled { position: relative; width: ' + 140 + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');
```

Here is my markup

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRestaurants" runat="server" CssClass="styled" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="false" Width="50">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All Restaurants"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

if anything still needed to be clear please let me know in comments. any help i would appreciate much.

Comment: Are you facing issue on particular browser? I have checked the demo on the site that you have linked and drop-down appears to be working correctly in both FF and IE8

Comment: @VinayC thanks for the response. i am facing issue in FF 18.0 and IE 9 and chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 m. The demo working fine even on my machine, but when i implemented the script on my webpage it doesn't seem to work

Comment: How are you accessing the `selectedValue` on the client side?

Comment: @Devjosh, suggest you to create sample (e.g. one at jsFiddle) that can illustrate the issue if that's possible.

Comment: @lanthe i need to access the value in code behind file but UI is not getting updated on client if i select any other iyem so the default item is always selected. a also made sure that selected=false in dropdown options

Comment: @Vikas: this is mentioned in that plugin website,   In Internet Explorer, the select lists are unstyled, but the checkboxes and radio buttons still look and function beautifully.

Comment: Bhai Try this:
$('select.styled').getAttribute('value');
var box = $('select.styled');
var text = box.selectedIndex >= 0 ? box.options[box.selectedIndex].innerHTML : undefined;
alert(text)

Comment: @neelesh we replaced the plugin at last when it was not workin in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an error in the javascript for the opacity setting that is stopping all further javascript processing.

Look at it in Firefox and use the Web Developer > Error Console to see if you see any error messages.